# Patterns in two catching groups work as intended but fail when put in backreference

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I write regex which should match a pattern consisting of only optional characters, but simultaneously I want it to doesn't match an empty string - I figured that I will use backreference for this, but when I try to apply it  my checks stop working: probably I lack in understanding of backreference but please give me a hint where I am making a mistake, my regex:

```
(?<pat>^[10]+$)(\k<pat>0*(1(10)*(0|(11))((01*0)(01)*1|(00))*1)*0*)
```

**Both subpatterns applied - no matches - regardless if correct or wrong**

[image]

**Only the second pattern applied (with additional checks for anchors - all correct matches work but also matches empty line**

[image]

**Only first pattern applied: matches any combination of 1 and 0**

[image]

Also, I have a secondary question: If I am using backreference can I use anchors `^` and `$` to check if the whole pattern matched by the first group is matched in backreference?
As requested in the comments here are inputs

```
Those should match:
101
000
1010
10100
Those should NOT match (empty string in first row):

101110101
1110001
1000
11
```

and patterns:

```
^[10]+$
^0*(1(10)*(0|(11))((01*0)(01)*1|(00))*1)*0*$
(?<pat>^[10]+$)(\k<pat>0*(1(10)*(0|(11))((01*0)(01)*1|(00))*1)*0*)
```

Comment: Hi there, please provide the samples and all attempted regexes (inputs: matching, non matching) **in plain text format** so whoever wants to help you will be able to copy and test their solution.

Comment: You can just add a *word boundary*, e.g. [`^\b0*(?:1(?:10)*(?:0|11)(?:01*0(?:01)*1|00)*1)*0*$`](https://regex101.com/r/gwRqnH/2) This will force a *word character* which digits belong to.

Comment: @bobblebubble - your solution works, but not solves my problem, which is - why backreference is not working for this case, regardless +1 for you ;)

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @BJagger As far as I know `\k<grp>` ist a [reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) to what was matched by the referenced group. [`(?<grp>abc)123\k<grp>`](https://regex101.com/r/zEvg1h/1) is the same like using e.g. [`(?<grp>abc)123\1`](https://regex101.com/r/uHcsBk/1) or [`(abc)123\1`](https://regex101.com/r/6K7mJu/1). Instead of the `\b` you could also use a lookahead to check if next character is not the end `(?!$)` or require at least one character `(?=.)`  but those are a bit less efficient than the `\b` "trick".

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern you have this `(?<pat>^[10]+$)` followed by `\k<pat>` which matches the characters that were captured by the named group `pat`.

But as you only match `0` or `1` and you have an anchor `$` that asserts the end of the string, there is no more text to match after it by the backreference.

As you don't want to match empty strings, you can write the pattern as:

```
^(?<pat>0*(1(10)*(0|11)(01*0(01)*1|00)*1)+0*|0+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<pat>` Named group `pat`

  - `0*` Match optional zeroes
  - `(` Start group to repeat as a whole part

    - `1(10)*(0|11)(01*0(01)*1|00)*1` The initial pattern
  - `)+` Close group and repeat this part 1 or more times to prevent matching an empty string
  - `0*` Match optional zeroes
  - `|` Or
  - `0+` Match 1+ times a zero to prevent matching an empty string
- `)` Close group `pat`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M0TsZo/1).

**Note** that I have removed some of the outer capture groups like `(11)` and `(00)` and `(01*0)` which are unnecessary for a match only.

If you are only interested in the named group *pat* you can use non capture groups `(?:` instead:

```
^(?<pat>0*(?:1(?:10)*(?:0|11)(?:01*0(?:01)*1|00)*1)+0*|0+)$
```